# Dolphin Scheduler UI not opening after installation in Linux server - 3.1.8, Linux 9

Tags: job-scheduler

Team,
Dolphin Scheduler ver - 3.1.8 installed in Linux RHEL 9.0
After installation Zookeeper, MySQL and all services (Api-server, Master-server, Worker-server, Alert Server) started successfully.
Even when I am giving the below command
curl -Lv http://localhost:12345/dolphinscheduler/ui
returns success ie 200 code.

How to open the Dolphin Scheduler UI in web browser? or any other setup required from the Linux server?